# How to write into .ini file using Qt C++?

Tags: c++, qt, ini

I'm trying to write a path into config.ini file using C++ QT.

```
QSettings settings(QString(":/config.ini"), QSettings::IniFormat);
settings.sync();
settings.beginGroup("Dir_Path");
settings.setValue("path",new_ini_path);

settings.sync();
```

I expect my config.ini to get updated on setting the value "new_ini_path".

Comment: You need to close it with `endGroup()` , and check your path with `QFile oFile(oSettingsFilePath); oFile.exists();`

Comment: Is it a valid file path `":/config.ini"`?

Comment: @sachinmurali When you use the prefix `":"` you indicate that a file in the qresource, and all the files within the qresource are **read-only**.

Comment: @vahancho yes after printing in the console it's returning new_ini_path .But it is not updating my config.ini file

Comment: @sachinmurali, your config file normally will be updated after `QSettings::sync()` call or when `setting` object will be destroyed.

Comment: @Simon ya tried using endGroup()

    QSettings settings(QString("./config.ini"), QSettings::IniFormat);

    settings.beginGroup("Dir_Path");
    settings.setValue("path = ",new_ini_path);


    settings.endGroup();
Still same config.ini

Comment: @eyllanesc so how can i make it R/W format

Comment: @sachinmurali You do not have to use qresource, use a normal file, for example change `":/config.ini"` to `"config.ini"`

Comment: @sachinmurali call `settings.sync()` after `settings.endGroup();`. QSettings update the data after closing the application unless you call sync(), on the other hand that .ini file will be created next to the executable

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks for the help. It's working...

Comment: @eyllanesc Is there any way to use as qresource file because of my path changes in different systems.